# de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification plug in phonegap not working

Tags: cordova, notifications, local

I used this plugin which was working fine till may 9th 2015 and now not working and not able to reinstall either. Why is this?

Comment: Edit some code here. No one can predict what change you've done in it.

Comment: Thanks Nehil for responding. The issue was with some changes made to plugin and was made to work for only cordova 3.6 to 4.0 versions. When removed that, it was working fine.